# R: Keeping only part of a list & is it possible to reverse cbind?

Tags: r, sorting, bar-chart, reverse, cbind

I have two lists of 37 items each (I put 3 here as an example):

```
vacancy.locations <- c("Amsterdam", "Zuid Holland", "Utrecht")
count.locations <- c("11", "9", "40")
```

I binded these two lists together `locations <- cbind(vacancy.locations, count.locations` so that I could sort in descending order `sortedlocations <- locations[order(-count.locations),]` and not lose the fact that 11 belonged to Amsterdam and 40 to Utrecht. 
However, now I want to only keep the 10 locations with the highest count. Can anyone help me do that?
After this I want to plot the top 10 locations in a barplot. Currently I'm trying that with the sortedlocations, however I only get 1 bar in the chart with all locations combined.

```
barplotLocations <- barplot(height=sortedlocations, las=2, main="locations in vacancies", xlab="locations", ylab="number", cex.axis = .5, cex.names = .75)
```

Help? :)

Comment: hey using `c()` in that context would give you a `vector`. You get a list by using `list()`.

Comment: **1**.order `count.locations` desc. **2**. use either `df[1:10,]` or `head(df,10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is an easy way of doing it with ggplot2

```
vacancy.locations <- letters
count.locations <- sample(1:1000, length(letters))

location = cbind.data.frame(vacancy.locations,count.locations)
location_sorted =  location[order(-count.locations),]

top_location = location_sorted[1:10,]
top_location[,1] = factor(top_location[,1], levels = top_location[,1][order(top_location[,2])])
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=top_location, aes(x=vacancy.locations, y=as.factor(count.locations))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: thanks! I'm a bit confused about the beginning part though. my vacancy.locations was a c("...","...","...) and yours is just the word letters so hwo does that work? and as for count.locations.. kind of the same question, i have very different things. So how does that work with what I have?

Comment: @J Green you have the same tipo of data, location is string and count is numeric so its no different. I just made somo random data to replicate what you wanted. The only different thing I did was making the location a factor so it could be graph properly. Is this working for your real data? Is yes accept the answer

Comment: I'm getting an error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class matrix

Comment: @J Green thats why i used `cbind.data.frame` because ggplot only works with data.frame, and you should convert your variable `count.location` to numeric with `as.numeric`.

Comment: omg wait yes it works now! thankss :D can i ask one more question? the top 10 locations are not showing in order, is it possible to do that? so have the highest count onthe left and the lowest count on the right?

Comment: @JGreen I dedidted the way i was sorting so it plots the bars increasing. Great it works, pleas accept the answer

Comment: edit: the ordering works! i missed out a tiny bit. thank you sooo much for the rest! i accepted your answer.

Comment: @JGreen what error are you getting? is your count variable numeric?